# Woocommerce add to cart error

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework, woocommerce-rest-api

Am currently working on woocommerce api, Since am new to this, I have some doubts.

Am using woocommerce rest API, for retreiving data, the problem is i can able to retrieve data from woocommerce after spending so much time. Now I'm getting problem in adding products to cart. The customer cant able to add product!

kindly, if anyone knows how to use add to cart option in woo commerce api

Answer (score 1):

if you are using woo-commerce rest API then you need to add your product in cart first the url will be like this ( http://yourwebsite.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=%ID%) then you can do the process like creating order and all.